# Dropping vertices of an overdetermined statics system graph

Tags: linear-algebra, statics, graph-theory

In statics, the problem of determining the tensions of K cables that connect a structure made of N points and keep all points in static equilibrium implies $ND$ systems of equations, where $D$ is the dimension of the space

For each edge, there is an associated tension, while for each vertice, there are $D$ equations for the incident edge tensions

There are cases where the system will be overdetermined, which means that some of the vertices produce redundant equations. The problem is: What is the criteria in the general case for choosing which vertices are redundant, and must be dropped? Is there some kind of criteria for this?